Indefinite matrix and congruence transformation
Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and consider the matrix
$$M =\begin{bmatrix} a-1 & a \\ a & b+a-1 \end{bmatrix}. $$
I want to derive the sharpest conditions possible for $a,b$ for which the matrix $M$ is negative semidefinite.
My approach was to use diagonal dominance, and I obtain the bounds $a \leq 0.5$, $b\leq 1$ and $2a + b \leq 1$. However, these conditions are only sufficient, since e.g. $a=0.4$ and $b=0.24$ leads to negative eigenvalues even if not fulfilling the third inequality. Is it possible to compute sharper conditions?
Thanks in advance!

Since $M$ is symmetric, $M$ is negative semidefinite iff both eigenvalues are non-positive. So you can compute the two eigenvalues and derive the exact condition $a,b$ need to satisfy for both eigenvalues to be $\le 0$.

I tried that, but I come up with condition involving squares and roots, which is not easy to check. I was thinking that there is a sharper linear condition... but maybe not

after rearranging the equation of the eigenvalues, I obtain $a\leq \frac{1-b}{2-b}$, which coincides with the other conditions when $a=0$ or $b=0$.

the right way to do this is congruence transformation...If $a=1,$  figure out the conditions on $b.$  If $a \neq 1,$   let $$P =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{a}{1-a} \ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$  and calculate $D = P^T MP.$  Then use Sylvesters Law of Inertia

Thanks, very elegant solution!
